# Annotated Ignore field get's ignored in servicestack reponse

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a request like this:

```
 ARequest : QueryBase<Person, Result>, IJoin<Person, OtherThing>
```

Person has the following field

```
[Ignore]
Public string Label { get { return FirstName + LastName; }
```

In my Result i have the following

```
public int Id; 
public string Label
```

However, if i add an `Ignore` attribute to a field it gets ignored. So whenever i execute everything the only thing returned is a list of id's and in the QueryResponse the `Label` is always empty, if i however return a `Person` instead of `Result` i get a completely filled response.

So the question is, how do i make sure OrmLite does not search for label in the database, but sets the label in my custom return object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After mythz explained to me the fact that if it doesn't map to your ormlite db it won't map to your resulting DTO later, i build a quick work around. Instead of returning my own response dto immediately in the following line:

```
ARequest : QueryBase<Person, Result>, IJoin<Person, OtherThing>
```

I just returned the person object:

```
 ARequest : QueryBase<Person>, IJoin<Person, OtherThing>
```

Then in my service i wrote a simple mapper along the following lines:

```
   QueryResponse<Result> response = result.ConvertTo<QueryResponse<Result>>();
    response.Results = new List<Result>();

    foreach (Person p in result.Results)
     {

       response.Results.Add(new Result{ Id = p.EmployeeId, Label = (p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName) });
     }
   return response
```

This way i made sure the label got filled with the firstname and the lastname, and yet did not have to redesign my result DTO so i could keep it very generic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but if you're only looking to return `Label` you should be able to add it to the returned DTO, e.g:

```
public class Result
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string Label { get { return FirstName + LastName } }
}
```

Comment: That is what i did, but it does not copy the label from my person to my result. However in my response it is just `public string Label {get; set; }` and in my person it is with a custom get

Comment: @HenkJansen Just the response should have the Label property as shown above. The Result DTO is what the DB result-set is mapped into, it's not going to map fields that don't exist in the OrmLite tables being queried.

Comment: Allright but i do not have access to the Firstname and lastname in the result dto due to the fact it being a generic response for all my combo boxes, they all just have a label.

Comment: I fixed it at the moment by writing my own mapper in my own service. So i do `QueryBase<Person> and then i just map the results to a new query response with objectlabels and return this, that way i can still use one DTO for all my combo boxes.

Comment: @HenkJansen cool, can you put your solution as an answer, sounds like it might be helpful for others.